# UWP MediaPlayer class does not use MediaExtesionManager::RegisterSchemeHandler to load custom stream in non-xaml application

Tags: c#, uwp

I already posted the question [at MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dca90d36-3806-424d-a394-0af7bde33a89/mediaplayer-class-does-not-use-mediaextesionmanagerregisterschemehandler-to-load-custom-stream-in?forum=netfxbcl), but with no luck.

So, maybe someone has a clue how to solve the problem:

I am trying to stream content to an appliaction using the [`MediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This works so far for supported formats and I can grab the video frames and render them by myself. When I try to use the [SimpleCommunication](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication) sample it works as long as I use a XAML application to playback the stream.

In my application, without XAML I use something like

```
mediaext_mgr = new Windows.Media.MediaExtensionManager();

mediaext_mgr.RegisterSchemeHandler("Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspSchemeHandler", "stsp:");
```

to register the custom scheme handler (basically the one from the sample) - but when I start the media player via `stsp://someip` I receive the unsupported stream error. Capturing also runs on the same machine. Streaming from my application to the modified sample (which uses the media element) works just fine.

The major question is, how can I make the `MediaPlayer` class using the registered (custom) scheme handler? I tried to overload the properties part in the [register-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaextensionmanager), but i am no sure how exactly. I also found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a74aa261-31eb-4bfb-976c-e30d84889581/get-pointer-to-the-imfmediasource-from-a-imfmediaengine?forum=winappswithnativecode) - but the answer is not exactly clear to me.

Comment: 1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a74aa261-31eb-4bfb-976c-e30d84889581/get-pointer-to-the-imfmediasource-from-a-imfmediaengine?forum=winappswithnativecode

Comment: 3) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaextensionmanager